# Cannnot get columns metadata using java.sql.Connection class

Tags: java, oracle, connection, metadata, production

I have 2 Installations of a software where in some part of the code the java.sql.Connection class attempts to get the metadata of the columns, I use the following code:

```
   public class DbColumnRules {
        public static void loadMetaDataColumns(final Connection conn) {
        try {
           String schema = conn.getMetaData().getUserName();
           RsultSet columns = conn.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, "CATEGORY", "%");
           while(columns.next()){
               //Name of column
               System.out.println("Name: " + columns.getString(4));
               System.out.println("Length: " + columns.getInt(7));
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
   }
```

Let's suppose that the java Connection class successfully establish the communication. In the production enviroment the code does not print the metadata and my client has told me that the priveleges of the two db users are the same, but the DBs are different instances, one for each user. I use Oracle 11g.

So here is the question: How can I know with a query the privileges of a user over a DB? Does the user of the app have to have an especial privilege to get the columns metadata using the java.sql.Connection class?

Comment: Are you using same user name for connections or are they different? Can you try printing the `String schema = conn.getMetaData().getUserName();` and see what is coming in production?

Comment: The users name are different. In testing enviroment my client has _SuiteTest_ as user name and _SuiteTest_ as BD name, in production enviroment he has _SuiteProd_ as user name and _SuiteProd_ as BD name. He says that the privileges of both users over theirs DBs are the same, but obviously there is something different and I can not figure out what, I am not an Oracle DBA. And yes, if I print the String 'schema' it shows right.